# Case statement usage within scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody explain why this code won't work for me?

```
create function dbo.fn_dis (@num int)
returns nvarchar(30)
as
begin 
    declare @catch nvarchar(30)

    case 
        when @num = 1 
            then set @catch = 'Active'
        else set @catch = 'Discontinued'
    end

    return @catch 
end
```

On the other hand an if statement works just fine:

```
create function dbo.fn_dis (@num int)
returns nvarchar(30)
as
begin 
    declare @catch nvarchar(30)

    if @num = 1
        set @catch = 'Active'
    else
        set @catch = 'Discontinued'

    return @catch
end
```

I didn't find any restriction on using case statements within scalar functions on the web

Thanks a lot for the help ! appreciated :)

Comment: CASE is an **expression**, not a control-of-flow statement. You assign your variable using the form of "set xxx = case .... end;" And for future reference. post the obvious syntax error you encountered rather than the misleading "doesn't work"

Comment: More to the point: this has nothing to do with scalar functions. That syntax doesn't work in a bare SQL batch either. And I strongly recommend you don't use scalar functions as they are major performance killers. An *inline* Table Function may be useful in some situations

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a function for this, you can at least bring it down to a single statement... However, it seems like a simple
inline case would be better

```
create function dbo.fn_dis (@num int)
returns nvarchar(30)
as
begin 
 return case when @num = 1 
             then 'Active'
             else 'Discontinued'
        end

end
```

Just to expand my inline comment

```
Declare @num int = 1

select Option1 = case when @num = 1 then 'Active' else 'Discontinued' end
      ,Option2 = IIF(@num=1,'Active','Discontintued')
```